# Exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows in procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

After call procedure get below error, when nested table contains more than one value.

is it possible put NEW_ID variable in FORALL block or other solution?

ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

```
procedure EMP_INSERT (
    P_EMP employees_nt
)
as
   NEW_ID number;

begin

   FORALL i IN 1 .. P_EMP.COUNT
        Insert into test (val_1) values (P_EMP(i)) RETURNING new_id into NEW_ID;
        Insert into test2 (val_2) values (NEW_ID);   
        //Is it possible put here NEW_ID to null?

end;
```

Comment: What value you are inserting in test table? `P_EMP(i).????` ?  You can set NEW_ID to null.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai In test table I insert 1 or 2, but in test2 I insert RETURNING value from first insert in table test

Comment: Assuming `test.new_id` is being populated by a sequence?

Comment: @Kevin Seymour,  yes sequence generate id (primary key)!

Comment: I have posted an answer, but in the future you MUST include a minimum reproducible example or at least some DDL, DML to start with: the burden of asking a clear question is on you and not on those you are asking for help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your collection P_EMP contains more than 1 row causing the the Returning clause to return more than 1 row, but you are attempting to return them in a scalar. You cannot do that. You need to create a collection and return into that collection.

```
create type  new_id_list_nt is table of integer;
create or replace 
procedure emp_insert ( p_emp employees_nt ) 
as
   new_id_array new_id_list_nt; 
begin
    forall i in indices of p_emp
          insert into test1(val_1) values(p_emp(i)) 
          returning t1_id bulk collect into new_id_array; 

        
   insert into test2 (val_2) 
        select column_value 
          from table(new_id_array);   
    
end emp_insert;
```

The collection used to return into must be defined either at the schema level or in a package. If locally defined it cannot be references via SQL.  See [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e177536ccfa0863b27e000f6c3b5f688).

*Note:* I used the INDICES OF rather than "1 .. p_emp.count". This is because the procedure cannot know that the collection is dense (ie not missing index values) which "1 .." requires, The "indices of" properly handles sparse collections.  
*Something you may want to try:* Rather than a Forall use the TABLE function to insert as is done in the second insert.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are bulk inserting you have to bulk return the values from the first FORALL.  You can then use those to do another FORALL to insert into your second table.

```
drop table t2;
drop table t;
drop sequence t2_seq;
drop sequence t_seq;

create sequence t_seq start with 100;
create sequence t2_seq;
create table t (
       t_id  number default t_seq.nextval not null,
       val_1 varchar2(10)
);
create table t2 (
       t2_id number default t2_seq.nextval not null,
       t_id  number);
declare
  type t_val_tab is table of t.val_1%type;
  type t_id_tab is table of t.t_id%type;
  
  l_val_tab t_val_tab := t_val_tab();
  l_id_tab t_id_tab;
begin
  l_val_tab.extend(3);
  l_val_tab(1) := 'a';
  l_val_tab(2) := 'b';
  l_val_tab(3) := 'c';
  
  forall i in l_val_tab.first .. l_val_tab.last
  insert into t(val_1) values (l_val_tab(i))
  returning t.t_id bulk collect into l_id_tab;
  
  forall i in l_id_tab.first .. l_id_tab.last
  insert into t2(t_id) values (l_id_tab(i));
end;
/

select * from t2;
/*
t2  t
1   100
2   101
3   102
*/
```